# How to convert a string to a url encoded

Tags: c#, url, encoding

I want to be able to convert for example ™ to `%99` but i dont know what encoding is that 
I tried looking at httputility class but i dont get `%99` i get other wierd signs can you please help me? thanks
Im using C#

I want to do that so my the login would work with all chars like ™ im using http post method for a vb forum i need first to correct the encoding

EDIT : Not sure but can i just change the Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
to something that accepts signs like trademark so it would work?

Comment: @user959615 - Welcome to Stackoverflow. Since you mention [`HttpUtility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx), is it safe to assume you're using C#? If so, you might want to indicate that more clearly in your question. Right now, it might be regarded as a candidate for closing as it's very vague.

Answer (score 1):

From the subject it seems that you are trying to encode given string to url string, e.g. changing something like user@email.com to user%40email.com so it can be in a url http://www.example.com?email=user%40gmail.com

Can you provide a little more information?

If you are trying to pass the string through a URL, than I highly recommend the HttpUtility.UrlEncode method to be on the safe side.

Comment: Yes im trying to do something like that , can you please give me example for HttpUtility.UrlEncode because i already tried and failed

Comment: You should post what you've tried and what you consider "failed".

Comment: when i try to encode for example ™  i get  %e2%84%a2 instead of %99

Comment: @user959615 why do you expect %99?

Comment: try navigating to www.google.com/?™ the url is auto changed to www.google.com/?%99 i want to know what encoding is that?

Comment: So I copied the url www.google.com/?™ and pasted to my chrome browser address bar, pressed enter, and ™ did not change to %99 for me. Maybe I screwed up the copy or navigation process. Now in C# HttpUtility.UrlEncode("a@a.com™") which did generate "a%40a.com%e2%84%a2" which should be ok, because passing that string into HttpUtility.UrlDecode("a%40a.com%e2%84%a2") which generated original string "a@a.com™". So I guess is it really important for you to have %99?? because decode will get you the original string again.

Comment: Well i dont knwo what encoding is that ? I tried to change the trademark sign with %e2%84%a2 but didn't work , but %99 works fine i dont want trademark sign in the end of the day i want to know what encoding is that and how to convert it , thanks